# Can I use Stack Overflow's CSS?

Tags: discussion, licensing

I am trying to build a design exactly like Stack Overflow's profile badges. Can I just copy and use it? With open source (*not* commercially)?

Comment: This question admittedly rides the line of being on-topic here; it's _kind of_ a tech question, which belongs on the main site, but it's also a question about Stack Exchange's own technology, which can live here... Hm.

Comment: it's a question about stackoverflow. This question on SO Main wouldn't be on topic, just like asking if you could use a design from any other website wouldn't be on topic.

Comment: @zcoop98 No, it's not a tech question. Licensing is a legal question. That it happens to be directly "about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network" makes it, potentially, on-topic here on MSO. Given that the situation is relatively clear (i.e. there's not a lot of legal grey area, even if there are differences in how various portions of the CSS should be handled), it seems reasonable to have it as a question.

Comment: Related: [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange, Inc. Trademarks](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

Comment: @Van, you may have noticed that multiple people have edited your post to remove the space between the end parenthesis and the final question mark. Please stop adding it back in. In English, no space should appear before the ending punctuation of a sentence. See [the answers to this question on English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4645).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is provided under [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/), Stack Exchange's in-house design system, that they've [released publicly on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks#stacks) under an MIT license.

There's a [badge component](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/badges/) that can be used out of the box that will likely cover whatever you're trying to do.

*That said*, it's important to acknowledge the notice in the bottom right of the site footer:

[image: "site design / logo © 2021 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa. rev 2021.11.11.40730"]

**All** elements of the network's design, including the network's CSS, are copyright of Stack Exchange. They therefore aren't necessarily free to use, nor okay to distribute or relicense, with anything you design or make– so you can't unilaterally "just copy and use" site design elements.

But you *can* use Stacks, to make your *own* design(s), with most of the same bits and pieces Stack Exchange uses for their own.

Comment: So You mean I can only use those `styles` and `JavaScript` which is present in [Stacks](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Icons) But cannot use which isn't there? And If I use than I should attach [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6BR3.png) License Text in the `footer` ? And Even if I use any of the Styles just by `copying and pasting` than I have to include that license in every footer ,so they can't sue me?

Comment: @Van If you use someone else's code, then you need to comply with the license for the code which you use. For Stacks, that license is the MIT license [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/blob/develop/LICENSE.MD), which is directly linked from the repository's main [README.md](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks#stacks). If there is no license specified for *any* particular code that you find anywhere, then the default assumption that you should use is that is is copyrighted and that you have *no right to use it* (at all).

Comment: @Makyen, And Can I `copy and use` stack overflow's `css` code and add a `cc by-sa` license in the footer ? Would it work ?

Comment: @Van I'm confused. Why do you think you can do that? Where do you see that Stack Overflow has licensed their code under CC BY-SA? I'm not aware of anything that says that. The only things on Stack Exchange which I've seen that are licensed under CC BY-SA are *user contributions*. Stack Overflow's code isn't a user contribution. You're approaching this from the wrong point of view. No code that you find anywhere is available for you to use, *unless* there is an *explicit* written statement that says that it is licensed in a manner that is compatible with the use you are wanting to make of it.

Comment: I meant to say that, It's in the right corner of the page

Comment: @Van Then you appear to be misreading it. It says that the site design and logo are copyrighted by Stack Exchange Inc. It also says that *user contributions* are licensed under CC BY-SA. It does *not* say that anything other than the user contributions have *any* license granted to anyone. Note: while the copyright statement only says "site design / logo © 2021 Stack Exchange Inc", you should assume that *everything* is copyrighted and that *nothing* is permitted to be used *unless* there is an *explicit* license. That is the default of how things work, almost everywhere for almost everything.

Comment: Clear, I have to design my own CSS

Comment: @Van that's a safe bet in any case. Create your own CSS, source your own images (not through Google images!). Nobody can stop you from using a browser's inspection feature to be "inspired" by existing sites, of course.